# Cordova/Phonegap - camera photo to fullscreen canvas - set dimensions

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, camera, dimensions

I am using the apache cordova camera plugin to return photos from native camera in a fullscreen canvas inside the app.

How to specify correct `targetWidth` and `targetHeight` options for the camera in order to return a full viewport size (fullscreen) image?

I am using the viewport height as targetHeight but it doesn't works well, the final photo dimension is not == to viewport height and it's less height than the viewport, (for example viewport = 400px and image took = 350px in height) :

```
var picOptions = {
        'quality': 85,
        'encodingType': 0, //JPEG
        'destinationType': Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,//base64
        'targetHeight': window.outerHeight,
        'cameraDirection': 0, //back, use 1 for front camera
        'allowEdit': false,
        'saveToPhotoAlbum': false
      };

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function (data) {

        navigator.camera.cleanup();
      }, function () {

        navigator.camera.cleanup();
      }, picOptions);
```

thanks

Comment: either you write a formula for calculating the pixels shown, or you set a viewport width and height, or you take the solution you know have.

Devices are so different, the picture gets streched. On one device more than on the other, it's difficult.

Comment: @Sithys if i want to show the photo in fullscreen, i need to use the viewport height and width, but i don't know if native cameras allows ANY height possible... how to know this?

Comment: Well by "every device" you know i mean the most popular ones, but i mean android, has so many different sizes that the only thing i can do is to set camera photo height = window height , but this doesn't ensure me the camera will take the photo at that height without testing on all possible devices :(

Comment: i dont know if you can specify the width and height the camera takes. You can just set the viewport width and height as far as i know. You can set the picture height and with to variables which get filled with the correct, calculated values from the viewport via javascript.

Comment: @Sithys i already do this :( and indeed setting height to viewport height result in canvas scretched little bit compared to the original photo took :(

Comment: What about adding a device orientation plugin. then write a condition to check orientation and put the width and height parameter according to it.

Comment: @KRIZTE isn't it the same as using viewport width and height? orientation must be Portrait only in my case

Comment: Yeah.. viewport height will always be equal to window height. Have you checked in multiple devices? or trying to  dynamically set height = device height ??

Comment: Also have you added correct meta tag in index file? Can i know which device you are using??

Comment: @KRIZTE i am using ionicframework i don't know much about meta tags, i leave the default by ionic.... as for height i am testing on an android tablet hoping if it works on it it will work everywhere, i set **targetHeight: window.innerHeight**